# Angularjs - Filter selected option from other <select> components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I got N "select" components depending on some JSON data and the "options" are filled by an external API.
What i need is that when a option is select in one "select" component it should't be shown in the others components, i'm trying to apply a custom filter but i have no luck yet.

```
.filter('exclude',function(lodash) {

        //@param itemsArray: array of items 
        //which fills the options of the select component.

        //@param selectedItem: the selected <option>
        //from one of the <select> components.
        return function(itemsArray, selectedItem) {
            var output = itemsArray,
                filteredItemsArray  = [];

            if(selectedItem) {
                var idx = lodash.findKey(itemsArray, { name: selectedItem.name });
                filteredItemsArray.push(selectedItem[idx]);
                output.splice(idx, 1);
            }
            return output;
        }
    });
```

this should be the behaviour in the html:

```
<select ng-option="p in publi track by $index | exclude: pSelect[$Index])" ng-model="pSelect[$Index]">
     <option val="usa" selected>USA</option>
     <option val="arg">Argentina</option>
     <option val="col">Colombia</option>
     <option val="cnd">Canada</option>
<select>

<select ng-option="p in publi track by $index | exclude: pSelect[$Index])" ng-model="pSelect[$Index]">
     <option val="arg" selected>Argentina</option>
     <option val="col">Colombia</option>
     <option val="cnd">Canada</option>
 <select>

<select ng-option="p in publi track by $index | exclude: pSelect[$Index])" ng-model="pSelect[$Index]">
   <option val="col" selected>Colombia</option>
   <option val="cnd">Canada</option>
<select>
```

i tried this but this only deletes the item from the array and it never got selected.

What can i do?

Comment: please show how this is being implemented.... [mcve]

Comment: I update with the expected behaviour. @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to filter out the other `pSelect` values which you could do by passing in 2 arguments `pSelect` and the current index

Then  filter  values that exist in pSelect except for the current index

Something like:

```
ng-option="p in publi track by $index | exclude: pSelect :$index"
```

Comment: hopefully `pSelect` is an object correct? You would loop over key/values of pSelect and exclude items as long as key doesn't match the current index argument